# How to save a number as bytes16 in a smart contract and retrieve the number in javascript?

Tags: solidity, javascript, bytes

I have the following smart contract to clarify the issue.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Test {
    bytes16 number;

    function getNumber() public view returns(bytes16) {
        return number;
    }

    function setNumber(bytes16 _number) public {
        number = _number;
    }
}
```

So using javascript I convert a number to hex string like so `let hex = ‘0x’ + (3456).toString(16)` where `hex` is `0xd80`. Then I pass the value as an argument to `setNumber`.
The challenge is when I call `getNumber` what I receive in return is  `0x0d800000000000000000000000000000`. Like 28 zeroes is appended to the end.
Parsing this gives a wrong value. I parse like so `let num = parseInt(‘0x0d800000000000000000000000000000’, 16)`. And I get `1.7944577943096364e+37`.
How can one get the right value from this ‘0x0d800000000000000000000000000000’ or how to save the number as bytes16 without the extra zero digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to left pad it. When you pass `0xd80`, it is getting right padded as part of the encoding process (to take up 16 bytes).

```
let argument = "0x" + web3.padLeft("d80", 32);
```

This should give you `0x00000000000000000000000000000D80`